# Definition of log or ln by functional relation

Tags: functions, logarithms, definition

My son was working the other day with exercises such as: Find all the mappings $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ verifying

$$\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}, f(m+n)=f(n)+f(m).$$

As another example: Find all the mappings $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, f(x)f(y)=f(xy)+x+y.$$

I know that there several equivalent ways to introduce the natural logarithmic function but I was wondering how one can define it properly and consicely by means of the functional relation

$$f(xy)=f(x)+f(y).\qquad (1)$$

That is starting from this relation and not any prior knowledge of $\ln$ or $\exp$.
Find all applications $f$ from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that (1) is satisfied, posing all the necessary restrictions.

Thank you very much for any help, or pointing me out if the question is a duplicate.

Comment: Unless I’m misunderstanding, the logarithm does not satisfy the relation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$

Comment: Sorry, misprint! @Malady

Comment: @Malady. I made the correction. I apologize for the mistake. I guess I am bit of tired...

Comment: Note that $f(x)=f(1x)=f(1)+f(x)$ so $f(1)=0$. Then we have for some $k$ that $f(kx)=f(k)+f(x)$ giving us $f(kx)-f(x)=f(k)$, a constant. There are complications if $f(k) \leq 0$ for all $x$ which motivates us to require $f(x)$ to be increasing. This turns out to be sufficient to define the logarithm.

Comment: @CyclotomicField thank you very much. Could you please post a full answer? What are these complications? Further with just knowledge of this functional relation from where we get the constraint $x>0$?

Comment: Ummm, let x = e, y = e, then
$1= ln(e) ln(e) \neq ln( e*e ) + e + e =2+2e$ therefore
$f(e) f(e) \neq f( e*e ) + e+ e$

Comment: @nickalh I think either you misunderstood my question or I do not understand your comment. I provide two examples of functional relations that my son had encountered. My question was how can one define properly the natural logarithmic function starting from a question of the type : find all mappings $f$ such that $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$. (Sorry for any typos I am writing with my mobile phone).

Comment: Ahhh, I suspected that was what you meant.  Perhaps the transition from functional equations in general to the functional equation for log could be clearer in your question?  I find general formatting to be inconvenient at best on MSE.

Comment: I think you should probably just impose $x > 0$ yourself in the last equation. Any such function which is defined at $0$ will be identically $0$ ($f(0 \cdot x) = f(x) + f(0)$...). On the nonzero reals, any multiple of $\ln |x|$ does the job too. Without some sort of continuity condition there are badly behaved solutions to your equation, eg by composing a [discontinuous additive function $g$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) with the logarithm: $f(x) = g(\ln x)$.